# How is the parity condition determined for modular forms corresponding to $L(s, \chi_1) L(s, \chi_2)$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, dirichlet-series, parity

This [answer to a related question on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916982)  indicates the following:

- "This leads you to the conclusion that products like $\zeta(s)^2$ or $L(s, \chi_1) L(s, \chi_2)$ should correspond to modular forms; and this is indeed the case, at least half of the time (there is a parity condition you have to impose)."

> **Question**: How is the parity condition determined for modular forms corresponding to $L(s, \chi_1) L(s, \chi_2)$? Is it related to the parities of the two Dirichlet characters $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ (i.e. the values of $\chi_1(-1)$ and $\chi_2(-1)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for $L(\chi_1, s) L(\chi_2, s)$ to correspond to a modular form is that $\chi_1(-1) \chi_2(-1) = -1$. This is necessary, because otherwise the fudge factors in the functional equation don't match up (the shape of the functional equation of $L(\chi, s)$ depends on $\chi(-1)$). It is also sufficient because we can write down the corresponding modular forms directly (they are **Eisenstein series**).

More generally, for $L(s, \chi_1) L(s - n, \chi_2)$ to correspond to a modular form, it is necessary that $n \ge 0$ and $\chi_1(-1) \chi_2(-1) = (-1)^{n+1}$, and this is sufficient except in the bad case when $n = 1$ and $\chi_1 = \chi_2 = $ trivial character (in which case you don't get a modular form but something slightly weaker called a "quasimodular form").

Comment: I don't understand how $L(s, \chi_1) L(s, \chi_2)$ corresponds to an Eisenstein series. Shouldn't $c(n)=\chi_1(n)*\chi_2(n)$ (where * is Dirichlet convolution) correspond to the Fourier series coefficients of the Eisenstein series?

Comment: Yes, so this is $c(m) = \sum_{n \mid m} \chi_1(n) \chi_2(m/n)$. Now compare with https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/eisenstein.html#explicit-basis-for-the-eisenstein-subspace.